# Impinj Octane Sdk ENABLE_IMPINJ_EXTENSIONS : M_UnsupportedMessage

Tags: c#, rfid

I am using the .net SDK Impinj Octane 3.6.0 and when connecting to my reader (ThingMagic Sargas) it gives me the error ENABLE_IMPINJ_EXTENSIONS : M_UnsupportedMessage

Is there a workaround for this so I don't get unsupported messages?

```
var Reader = new ImpinjReader("192.168.178.196", "My Reader");
Reader.ConnectTimeout = 6000;
Reader.Connect(); // throws Impinj.OctaneSdk.OctaneSdkException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LLRP is a standard, as defined by GS1, but it allows for custom extensions. And vendors have implemented so much of them, that cross compatibility is not very good.

What happens, is that the Impinj library tries to use one of its LLRP extensions (for Impinj readers) on the Sargas, that doesn't support those extensions, hence the error. I think you cannot make this work.

What you can do:

- Jadak has their own LLRP library for the Sargas. Is there any reason why you don't use that one?
- The Impinj Octane SDK is based on libltk, which is a old, really old, LLRP implementation that auto-generates C# code based on Xml files. Google very well and you'll find it.
- Or use an RFID platform like https://nedap-harmony.com that does all the nitty gritty LLRP for you, and presents a simple REST interface and data stream.

Comment: Thanks so much Danny for your detailed answer. I wasn't aware the implementation of the standard was so fragmented. The Jadak Mercury API is windows only, I am wanting a cross platform solution so I can run on RiPi.
I will look into Dedap Harmony as that solution looks like it does everything I need.